# Push error in browser console on first time connection Safari 5.1.7

Tags: primefaces, websocket, atmosphere

I am using PrimeFaces 5.1, JSF 2.1 and tomcat 7 and my application is in AWS. atmosphere version 2.2.2.

This issue occurs in  Safari 5.1.7.

My website is on https - self signed ssl.

On connecting for first time the below error is displayed, after which the connection is opened successfully. But the previously pushed data is available due to the error in connection.

On searching, found out that this issue may appear if the application runs on https. Can i do anything to resolve this issue without removing https security?

This issue does not appear when testing the same in localhost http but appears in localhost https.

Error is

> WebSocket supported, Polling will be disabled!!
>   wss://uat.elasticbeanstalk.com/primepush/service/push/service/push?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.2.4-javascript&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&X-atmo-protocol=true
>
> WebSocket network error: The operation couldnt be completed. (OSStatus error
>   -2146762487.)
>
> Websocket failed. Downgrading to Comet and resending
>
> push connection opened
>
> Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html.

Web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor</param-name>
        <param-value>org.atmosphere.interceptor.ShiroInterceptor</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```